# Which STL algorithms are safe to use with single-pass input iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, language-lawyer

Which or what kind of STL algorithms are safe to use in a standard-compliant STL implementation?

In other words: which or what kind STL algorithms are required by the standard to be single-pass?

If the exhaustive list would be too long, a way to identify those which are safe is also OK.

Comment: One pass algorithms. :)

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: All the single pass algorithms like `accumulate`, `copy`, `transform`... Do you want someone to click through all of cppr and enumerate them all? What for?

Comment: Is cppr an authoritative reference?

Comment: The C++ Standard makes no mention of one pass algorithms.

Comment: So, effectively, all bets are off?

Comment: @quant_dev Of course not, but in these things, it is usually right. Alternatively, you can scroll through Ch. 18-30 in the standard. But again, what for?

Comment: @quant_dev The authoritative reference is the ISO specification. Each algorithm specifies its requirements on iterators, including if iterators can be "single-pass input iterators" (which the spec simply refers to as `InputIterator`).

Comment: @BaummitAugen I want to know what algorithms are safe to use when using single-pass algorithms (e.g. iterating over a file).

Comment: @bames53 Are you sure that `InputIterator` implies single pass? cppr says otherwise.

Comment: @quant_dev Many. Every one that requires at most `InputIterators` for its template argument. Again, that would be a long list.

Comment: @quant_dev If it uses an `InputIterator`, this implies it's a one-pass algorithm.

Comment: @quant_dev *"cppr says otherwise"* No it does not.

Comment: @erip Thanks, that's the kind of answer I needed.

Comment: If you change this to "How can I tell if an STL algorithm is safe to use with single-pass input iterators?" you might get a better response.

Comment: @immibis what part of the present answer is unsatisfactory?

Comment: @jaggedSpire I should've said a better reception. As in, less people will decide it's a bad question.

Comment: @immibis oh good. I was worried I'd left something off. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: @immibis The rules for "bad" and "good" questions on SO seem a bit arbitrary to me. More like a mob rule. But that's a meta-discussion.

Comment: @quant_dev Yes they do. Generally, don't ask for a list of things with a particular property, because any list will probably miss some, and will become outdated easily. But asking how to tell if something has a property is okay.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Algorithms which operate on [`InputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator)s and [`OutputIterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator)s may by contract rely only on a single pass through the range they operate over.

From cppreference<sup>1</sup>:

On [`InputIterator`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator):

> An InputIterator is an Iterator that can read from the pointed-to element. InputIterators only guarantee validity for single pass algorithms: once an InputIterator i has been incremented, all copies of its previous value may be invalidated.

and on [`OutputIterator`s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator)

> Assignment through the same value of an output iterator happens only once: algorithms on output iterators must be single-pass algorithms.

---

This is a list of those algorithms which have arguments of `InputIterator` and `OutputIterator`:

- [`all_of, any_of and none_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)
- [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)
- [`count and count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count)
- [`mismatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch)
- [`equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)
- [`find, find_if and find_if_not`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)
- [`find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_first_of) offers `InputIterator` behavior for the first iterator pair
- [`copy and copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move)
- [`fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n)
- [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)
- [`generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n)
- [`remove_copy and remove_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy)
- [`replace_copy and replace_copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace_copy)
- [`unique_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy)
- [`is_partitioned`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_partitioned)
- [`partition_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy)
- [`partial_sort_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy), offers `InputIterator` behavior for the first iterator pair
- [`merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)
- [`includes`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes)
- [`set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)
- [`set_intersection`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)
- [`set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference)
- [`set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union)
- [`lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare)
- [`accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)
- [`inner_product`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product)
- [`adjacent_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference)
- [`partial_sum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum)

added in C++17:

- [`for_each_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n)
- [`sample`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample) either the input or the output iterators may be single pass, but not both--either the input must satisfy `ForwardIterator` or the output must satisfy `RandomAccessIterator`.
- [`exclusive_scan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/exclusive_scan)
- [`inclusive_scan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inclusive_scan)
- [`transform_reduce`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce)
- [`transform_exclusive_scan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_exclusive_scan)
- [`transform_inclusive_scan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_inclusive_scan)
- [`uninitialized_move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_move)
- [`uninitialized_move_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_move_n)

Interestingly, there are three algorithms *not* on this list that one might expect: [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), [`min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [`minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) are the standard's algorithms for finding the maximum, minimum and both the minimum and maximum value of a range. One might expect them to iterate over their given range only a single time, and thus require `InputIterator` arguments. Instead, they require `ForwardIterator` arguments, because rather than returning the *value* of the chosen element, they return an iterator to it. Since this violates the single pass requirement of an InputIterator, these algorithms are naturally left with a `ForwardIterator`.

---

<sup>1.  cppreference is backed on both counts by the standard (n4140 draft).</sup>

<sup>§24.2.3 [input.iterators] states that after `++r` where `r` is the input iterator, "any copies of the previous value of r are no longer required either to be dereferenceable or to be in the domain of =="</sup>

<sup>§24.2.4 [output.iterators] states for both the expressions `*r = o` and `*r++ = o` "After this operation r is not required to be dereferenceable."</sup>

<sup>Both sections contain notes that mention that the iterator in question is safe for single pass ranges, stating that "Algorithms on (input|output) iterators should never attempt to pass through the same iterator twice. They should be single pass algorithms." Of course, notes aren't binding.</sup>

Comment: Note that this does not mean that they can't do a multipass if given forward or stronger iterators.

Comment: @T.C. I seem to recall you saying as much on one of my own questions, oddly enough. :P

Comment: `once an InputIterator i has been incremented, all copies of its previous value may be invalidated.` So using `std::distance` on a pair of (non-forward) input iterators would invalidate the entire range?